# Sorting through a list of transactions to find the top 10 most popular

Tags: php, sorting

Okay so I have an array, laid out as follows (only the first item is shown):

```
array(600) {
  [0]=>
  array(12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1163"
    ["aliasID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-09"
    ["type"]=>
    string(12) "DD"
    ["description"]=>
    string(18) "GYM MEMBERSHIP"
    ["plusminus"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["amount"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["balance"]=>
    string(6) "50.00"
    ["ts"]=>
    string(19) "2019-01-27 22:32:29"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(3) "Gym"
    ["categoryID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["category"]=>
    string(10) "Recreation"
  }
```

In this instance there are 600 transactions.  I want to run through the list, find the 10 most popular (as in, the most frequent occuring) and display them.  How can I achieve this? I'm not great at sorting - but I wrote the following code to add them up:

```
foreach($transactions as $t) {
        if(isset($popular_dataset[$t['description']])) {
            $popular_dataset[$t['description']]++;
        } else {
            $popular_dataset[$t['description']] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Which gives me an array that I can view the highest ones, but I'm unsure as to how to proceed from here.  Any advice would be great - am I on the right path or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extract the `description` into an array and count the values, then sort descending and slice the first ten:

```
$popular_dataset = array_count_values(array_column($transactions, 'description'));
arsort($popular_dataset);
$top_ten = array_slice($popular_dataset, 0, 10);
```